# How to get where a object is initialized with ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I am having a specific class I want to take care of.

```
public class TargetClass {
   public TargetClass() { /* .. */ }

}
```

In my big project, I have multiple location that I create a new instance of this class

```
public class A {
   ...
   TargetClass obj = new TargetClass() // say line number 100
   ...
}
public class B {
   ...
   TargetClass obj = new TargetClass() // say line number 200
   ...
}
```

How could I use ASM to insert a field `initLocation` in the constructor and when `new TargetClass()` get called, the initLocation will record the line number of the init location, e.g., `package/path/A + L100`, `package/path/B + L200`

Comment: what is ASM exactly?

Comment: @roottraveller ASM is a library for the manipulation of Java bytecode (the question is tagged accordingly, and you can find additional info in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-bytecode-asm/info))

Comment: @roottraveller alternative way is also appreciated! I cannot modify the source so I think instrumentation is the right thing to do?

Comment: Do you know how to transform a class using `ClassReader` and `ClassWriter` in general? You only have to override `visitLineNumber`/`visitLabel` to remember the position and `visitMethodInsn` to detect and transform invokespecial instruction targeting to the right `<init>` methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple:

```
        ClassNode node = context.getInfo().getNode(); // You have to make ClassNode by yourself. 
        for (MethodNode method : node.methods) {
            int lineNumber = -1;
            ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> iter = method.instructions.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                AbstractInsnNode instruction = iter.next();
                if (instruction instanceof MethodInsnNode) {
                    MethodInsnNode invokeInsn = (MethodInsnNode) instruction;
                    if (invokeInsn.getOpcode() == Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL && invokeInsn.name.equals("<init>")) {
                        if (invokeInsn.owner.equals("Receiver")) { // Here we have to use internal class name. For example java.lang.Class = java/lang/Class
                            iter.previous();
                            iter.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.DUP));
                            iter.next();
                            iter.add(new LdcInsnNode(node.name + " " + method.name + method.desc + " L" + lineNumber));
                            iter.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.PUTFIELD, "Receiver", "initializationInfo", "Ljava/lang/String;"));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (instruction instanceof LineNumberNode) {
                    lineNumber = ((LineNumberNode) instruction).line;
                }
            }
        }
```

I just iterate over each instruction in each method. When I find `INVOKESPECIAL` I compare target method with `<init>`(internal name of constructor) and owner name with `Receiver`. You probably will replace it by name of your own class. 
When all of that conditions is true I insert `DUP` instruction before constructor invocation and `LDC` and `PUTFIELD` after that.

Test class

```
public class Transmitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Receiver r = new Receiver();

        System.out.println(r.initializationInfo);
    }
}
```

Result

```
java -cp main Transmitter
Transmitter main([Ljava/lang/String;)V L4
```